# Why std lib from GDC is not the same that phobos from DMD

Tags: d, dmd, phobos, gdc

For example, I can not compile using GDC 5.2.0 (2016-02-05T11:17:49.3234388) a program importing std.meta because that file is not found.

I was comparing the include folders between GDC and DMD and I found a great mismatch of versions.

```
\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\5.2.0\include\d\std     from GDC  5.2.0 
dmd2\src\phobos\std                                 from DMD2 2.070.0
```

This preventing that I can use GDC with confidence.

Anyone knows why includes of GDC are not the same Phobos library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDC and LDC lag behind DMD, as adapting the latest DMD changes with the respective compiler backends takes some time.

Note the DMDFE column on the downloads page:

http://gdcproject.org/downloads

It indicates which DMD version the corresponding release is based on.

Comment: I am aware about this lag between them, but I checked the GIT source control and I found that even DMD2  2.066 have meta.d.   Thus. GDC based on 2.066 should has it too. Phobos is different in GDC.

Comment: DMD 2.066.0 does not have a `meta.d` in Phobos. It's neither in the released zip/tar.gz files, nor [in git](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/tree/v2.066.0/std), so I don't know why you would say that 2.066 has a `meta.d`.

Comment: You are right, man. My bad, I don't know what I saw. My question is resolved now.